# How can I mark files with badges in Windows?

Tags: windows-8, label

Is there a way or a program that marks the icon of a file with a badge, similar to how Dropbox marks synced files with a green checkmark, and files that are currently syncing blue?

I'd use that to mark videos I've watched in a series.

Comment: yes, wiiMC does it automatically on Wii, and I love it. A total commander plugin would also be great, but couldn't find.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I couldn't find a better solution, so I've created an open-source project for that. Available at https://github.com/csomakk/IWatchSeriez
Its nothing special yet, but it does the trick, and I'll try to work more on it. I Watch Seriez, IWatchSeriez :)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can try something like [**UserInfoTip**](http://www.akslab.com):

> - Select some files or folders, assign icons for them, and add a description to be displayed in Explorer's popup windows.
> - You can easily notice the marked files among other files and recognize their types by the icons.

[image: 1]
[image: 2]
[image: 3]

---

Of course, nothing prevents you from [creating an Icon Overlay Handler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144123%28VS.85%29.aspx) of your own. You can get started by using [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/ExplorerIntegration.html)'s [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/843506/shell-icon-overlay-c), but remember that there's [a 15 overlay limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4411336/shelliconoverlayidentifiers-why-so-few) (which will get exhausted in no time if multiple programs attempt to set overlays), and icon overlays are not even recommended by people such as Raymond Chen.

Comment: Is there an easier way to mark things as watched? Something really simple like a checkbox that's remembered would be awesome.

Comment: @Ariane: Anything like this is likely to require some sort of shell extension, since it's not an in-built feature.

Comment: And I guess we're not lucky enough to have this exist, eh?

Comment: @Ariane: Well, I did link to a program above that adds an icon overlay handler, as requested by the OP. There might be other solutions/shell extensions available as well - obviously I did not bother to check out every single search engine result.

Comment: Why? Being a slave of lazy people isn't a career path for you? Damn! (I'm out, I'm out.)

Comment: @csomakk: Heh, maybe. If you can though, feel free to create and release the app; perhaps fame and fortune will come your way. :)

Comment: it would seem easier if I'd make a svn repo of my downloads folder, and check out to mark :D

Comment: So after installing the app you don't see "Manage Description" anywhere, in the context menu for files *or* folders? I think you may have installed **TagsForAll** instead of **UserInfoTip**.

Comment: No, the Explorer columns for comments/description aren't supported in Vista+, but the overlay icons should be supported. Did you try it?

Comment: yes, I didn't installed the correct one, but still doesnt work on Win8, only on XP. :( but thanks, Karan, a really great tip, I was looking for something like that.

Comment: wow.. I found out, that it works in total commander, even in Windows 8!!!! Thanks!

Comment: Oh well, good luck finding a better alternative (and if you do, let us know).

Comment: @csomakk: Cool app! Strictly speaking though it doesn't mark files with badges ***in*** Windows itself (it's kinda like using a separate spreadsheet or DB to mark viewed files), but quite useful nevertheless.

Comment: yes, I played around with marking them in Windows itself, but the API is quite limited, basically Dropbox uses half of the available icons already..

Comment: UserInfoTip is great.. if it worked consistently :'/ . In my Windows 10 x64, it worked the first time. After reboot, I couldn't get it to work again. :'( On to searching again for other programs like it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Rating in Windows Explorer as work around. Mark * as read.

From File's Properties, it allows me to do file Rating from (zero star ~ 5 stars).  Since I'm not using the rating feature to really rate a file, instead I use it for the purpose of marking it as a read file, no matter what file type it was. I also can sort out those read vs. unread files if I want.

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: From Files Properties, it allow me to do file Rating from (zero star ~ 5 stars), since I'm not using the rating feature to really rate a file, instead I use it for the purpose of marking it as a read file, no matter what file type it was. I also can sort out those read vs. unread files if I want.

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for a similar solution when I found this thread. I figured out a fairly simple way to achieve what you're looking to do (at least in this particular case.) Maybe it will help others that happen upon this.

If you have the appropriate permissions, you can view "Hidden" files in Windows. They show up as grayed/semi-transparent icons/thumbnails of the original.

First, be sure that you're able to see Hidden Files.

---

1. Open Folder Options by clicking the Start button , clicking Control Panel, clicking Appearance and Personalization, and then clicking Folder Options.
2. Click the View tab.
3. Under Advanced settings, click Show hidden files and folders, and then click OK.

---

Now all you need to do is right click each episode after viewing it, go to Properties, and check the "Hidden" box. It will remain there but grayed out, allowing you to keep your place!

Cheers!

Comment: Nice answer, but doesn't actually answer the question :/

Answer (score -1):

[See this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7AqA.png)

Click, show the hidden files from the folder options and hide the file you already viewed. Since you enabled to show the hidden files from the folder options windows will show the hidden files by blurring it. This way you can mark the viewed files See the photo attached that the DNA and RNA file is blurred.